# Unsubscribing from event when object is disposed

Tags: c#, system.reactive

What I'm trying to figure out is how to declaratively avoid the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception thrown when disposing of subscription to `FromEventPattern` observable when the observed object gets disposed of before disposing of the subscription.
Here's a simplified example:

```
void Main()
{
    EventSource oEventSource = new();
    
    var source = Observable.FromEventPattern<MyEventArgs>(
                h => oEventSource.MyEvent += h,
                h => {
                    //if (oEventSource != null) 
                    oEventSource.MyEvent -= h; // <--- error thrown here
                })
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs.Value)
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Subscribe(x =>
    {
        oEventSource?.RaiseMyEvent(x);
    });
        
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    oEventSource = null;
    
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    source.Dispose(); // <--- error thrown when disposing subscription
}


public class EventSource
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
    
    public void RaiseMyEvent(long x){
        MyEvent?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs(x));
    }
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEventArgs(long x) { Value = x;}
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot make sure the subscription is disposed of before disposing of the "EventSource" object because the object is defined in viewModel and it is bound to the View where the subscription takes place.

Checking if EventSource object exists before removing the handler stops the error being raised (`if (oEventSource != null)`), but won't it introduce a memory leak since the handler is never removed?

Comment: `oEventSource = null;` Why are you doing that?

Comment: Why not just capture over the `EventSource` rather than over `this`? Then EventSource would be in scope. However, I feel you have a fundimental misunderstanding about object lifecycles and GC. Normally, one does NOT set fields/variables to `null`.

Comment: I don't see any relation between unsubscribing an event and the Dispose of an object. Dispose doesn't destruct an instance, it's a pattern to get rid of unmanaged handles/memory which are not cleaned up by the garbage collector and is supported by the language _(such as `using(....)`)_

Comment: @MatthewWatson normaly in the real application the subscription is set up in the View and when the MainViewModel is disposed of and the EventSource object that is referenced by MainViewModel is disposed too. So I end up with the view's dependency property set to null. Later i try to unsubscribe in the view's unload event and get the exception. I was trying to isolate the problem but maybe have oversimplified it and introduced completely different issue.

Comment: @Aron thanks for your input, you are right about capturing over the EventSource, but I was trying to provide a working example of the problem I run into where the subscription and the events are in different places, maybe the example does not reflect my problem properly. (EDIT: normaly i wouldn't set the field to null but irl it is dependencyProperty that ends up being null)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen- Rx uses `Dispose()` to unsubscribe from an observable. The observable may or may not have any unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1):

there is much confusion to your logic and your style is not really using RX e.g sequence composability. However an answer to your question is simply unsubscribe your source uppon the condition you want

```
.Select(x => x.EventArgs.Value)
    .TakeUntil(l => oEventSource!=null)  //this line
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Thanks @Apostolis, I think you meant `TakeWhile`, `.TakeUntil` doesn't accept predicate as an argument

Comment: I agree that my example isn't perfect, but it is just to illustrate what happens when we pull the rug under `FromEventPattern` operator's feet with setting an observed property to null. I understand it is not what one is supposed to do, but this is just academic discussion :)

Comment: The answer would be to do this `//oEventSource = null;`.